# Set Visual Studio Formatting Options for an entire team

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

Different devs on our team have wildly different checkboxes here:

[image: Visual Studio Formatting Options]

and as a consequence Visual Studio keeps reformatting code and this really pollutes our commits.

What I want is to have a single *whatever* (`.reg` file or something) to run on each devs' computer so that these settings will be consistent.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712/visual-studio-2005-2008-how-can-you-share-force-all-developers-to-use-the-same

Answer (score 21):

Starting from VS2017, [`.editorconfig`](http://editorconfig.org/) files [are taken into account](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/) and allow to override local preferences. Put it at the root of your projects solution (or even higher), under source control in order to distribute it with your sources to each developer.

You can set .Net coding conventions through VS (since v15.3) specific properties, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options).

Example file:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = CRLF
insert_final_newline = true

[*.cs]
indent_style = tab
dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = true
csharp_space_after_cast = true

[*.xsd]
indent_style = tab

[*.json]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

[*.xml]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

[*.cshtml]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

For VS2017, the [IntelliCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-visual-studio) experimental extension has a feature for generating editor config files, see this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-intellicode-inferring-coding-conventions-for-consistent-code/) for more information.

Starting from VS2019, VS can create an editorconfig file from ["New File" templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019#add-an-editorconfig-file-to-a-project), from [your code base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/code-style-inference) (right-click a project > Add > New EditorConfig) or from [your current VS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019#code-styles-in-editorconfig-files) (Tools > Options > Text Editor > [C# or Basic] > Code Style > General).

Comment: Is there a way of automatically exporting .editorconfig according to my current settings? Doing it by hand and looking up every single property would take hours.

Comment: Good question blade.  I added a suggestion here that you can vote for. I too think that it would be great to be able to export the clang or editor.config file from current options initially instead of trying to manually recreate an entire config file. 
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/34290964-export-formatting-options-to-clang-or-editor-confi

Comment: It seems to be available since July, see the last sentence I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can export the desired settings from one of the visual studio instances from the tools menu using the option "Import and Export settings". This will save the settings to a .vssettings file (which is actually a xml file) holding stuff like

```
<PropertyValue name="TabSize">4</PropertyValue>
```

You can then either import these settings on the other machines through the user interface (same menu option) or you can load them from the commandline using

```
devenv.exe /Resetsettings <your settingsfile>
```

This commandline settings is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, this does not export the formatting settings Anton showed in his screenshot.

Comment: IN VS2102 exporting "All Settings/Options/Text Editor/C# Editor" does export these settings e.g. <PropertyValue name="NewLines_Braces_Method">1</PropertyValue>

Comment: Same for VS2013 You can exactly specify what is and what isn't exported.