# fix name violation for camelcase variables (visual studio warning)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, naming-conventions, naming

As I read about naming convection in asp.net [Here](https://dotnetdaily.net/web-development/tutorials/c-coding-guidelines-series-naming-conventions)

> Use Camel Case for variables and method parameters

So i should use camel case naming for **variables** and **method parameters** but I don't know why visual studio warn me about these names:

```
public class Ad
    {
        public DateTime? startTimeLimitation { get; set; }
        public DateTime? endTimeLimitaion { get; set; }
        public Payment payment { get; set; }
    }
```

As *fix name violation*

So should I Ignore this warnings or I missed something about naming convection?

Comment: This might fix your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856186/naming-rule-violation

Comment: @SurajS you mean the problem is visual studio? and my naming rule is right?

Comment: Remember my question is not how to disable warnings.

Comment: Your naming convention is fine. Its all developer dependent. Cannot be forced.

Comment: You did not show any variable or method parameter. You show us properties and the naming convention says: Use pascalCase for properties.

Comment: @SirRufo Yes. as you said i made a mistake between naming a property and a parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use camel case for local variables and pascal case for class level variables like

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime? StartTimeLimitation { get; set; }

    void MyMethod()
    {
        int localVariable = 0;
        //some other code
    }
}
```