# Suppress Naming Rule Violation IDE1006 in Visual Studio 2017 for MAC

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

How can I globally suppress the warning `IDE1006` *Naming Rule Violation* in Visual Studio 2017 for **MAC**?

All the answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856186/naming-rule-violation) probably refer to a tab in the options dialog on **windows** that doesn't seem to be present/available in the **MAC** version.

I found a global suppression file called `GlobalSuppressions.cs`, which I added the following to:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles", Justification = "TBD", Scope = "member", Target = "*")]
```

Which doesn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use menu **Visual Studio > Preferences > Text Editor > Source Analysis > C# >Code Rules** and look in the list for "IDE1006" and change the Action to "Hidden"

[image]

Alternately, you can hover over the squiggly line under the name, click on the "tip" icon to open a submenu, then select **Suppress > Suppress IDE1006 > In Suppression file**:

[image]

That should add the GlobalSuppression.cs file to the project and populate it with the necessary attribute to suppress the warning for that specific method:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:MyNamespace.MyType.swe_calc(System.Double,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)~System.Int32")]
```

If you select **In Source**, then an inline #pragma compiler directive is added to the source code file around the method in question.

Since you seem to want this always ignored, then go with the first option in the Preferences which worked to suppress the warning on my end.

AS for why your SuppressMessage attribute did not work, I don't think you can use "*" for the Target. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2017#global-level-suppressions

> **Note**
>
> Target always contains the fully qualified item name.

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally! Funny thing is: The set of rules under **Code Rules** in the preferences was empty in my case. Weird.

Comment: That is weird. File with that xml should be at `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio/7.0/RuleSet.global`. Sounds like something did not happen during install that should have, or perhaps the version of VS for Mac that you have installed?

Answer (score 3):

For global suppression modify your code to this:

> [assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles", Justification = "TBD", Scope = "module")]