# How to suppress one particular naming rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I prepend an underscore to the names of my local methods, for example:

```
private bool _DoSomething() {..}
```

VS 2019 gives me an `IDE1006` (Name Violation) for this construct. Is there a way to suppress the name violation ONLY for this particular naming convention? I don't want to suppress all name violation warnings, just this particular construct.

Comment: First question is why are you ignoring the IDE's warning?

Comment: Have you tried using a #pragma statement? https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/09/01/hide-compiler-warnings.aspx

Comment: duplicate... I believe the third answer down in this link has your solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856186/how-to-get-rid-of-naming-rule-violation-messages-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your customized Naming type by the following steps.

**Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Code Style → Naming**

Click "Manage naming styles" to create a new naming style as shown below.
[image]

Then create the custom naming

[image]

After this, **click "manage specifications" → modify "Method" → select the accessibilities you need**.

[image]

**Last but not least, close Visual Studio and re-open it.**