# Is there a TFVC Check-In policy that makes TFVC require a user to do a Get Latest before checking in?

Tags: git, tfvc

The team I'm working on uses TFVC. In the last 3 years I've been learning Git. I much prefer Git to TFVC. I'm trying to encourage my teammates to go toward Git, but at least for now we're still using TFVC.

One feature of Git that I **REALLY** like is the way Git will stop you from just pushing your commits to remote, without first performing a pull, or at least a fetch. This is a feature I really wish TFVC had. At the agency I work at, we have maybe 200 developers or other users who might use TFS. Some of them have a nasty habit of just checking in their code, regardless of what other people have checked in before them. Sometimes it wipes out what others have checked in. Sometimes it breaks builds. Then there's the inevitable, "Oh, gee, I'm sorry..." line. Or a few might quote Grace Hopper's famous line, "Better to seek forgiveness, rather than permission". (Assuming they even know who Admiral Hopper was. And personally, even though Admiral Hopper is credited with that quote, I don't believe she would have approved of some developers stomping over other developers' code, then flippantly quoting her.)

I went looking for a way of duplicating the same behavioral enforcement that Git applies to performing a `push`. I came across the concept of a [TFVC check-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-check-policies?view=azure-devops). This looked ideal, so I looked into adding a check-in policy (per the link I shared) but didn't see anything that would remotely do what I understand Git is doing when it requires a user to perform a pull before pushing to origin.

So, is there a way of adding a check-in policy which will require users to first perform a get latest before they perform a check-in?

I'm working with TFS 2015 and VS 2019.

Comment: As a maintainer of the git-tfs bridge to avoid this kind of TFVC annoyance, I understand you. My point of view is that it is difficult to achieve, that's why I think there is none, because how TFVC store all the branches and project in a flat way in the collection and there is no clear separation. So depending on what is contained in your workspace, a folder could have a different last changeset ID than another making things difficult to define what is the lastest. Git-tfs force you, like git, to have the last version but it will only work if all use it but you can't force them to use it.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I could only hope, but shouldn't be surprised that there isn't such a check-in policy. Man, I hope I can coax my colleagues to leave TFVC behind.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard check-in policy for TFVC to enforce a get-latest prior to check-in. It would be possible to create one though, a check-in policy is just a piece of .NET code running inside Visual Studio.

But you'd need to distribute that to all of the users in your development organization, because even though you can configure a policy on the server side, TFS won't ensure the code to run the policy is sent to all of the Team Explorers out there. And you need to create a version of the policy for every version of Visual Studio that's used in your organization.

I've written a number of blogs on the topic of custom checkin-in-policies here:

- https://jessehouwing.net/tag/tfvc-checkin-policy/

There is, however, a visual studio setting that you may be able to enforce through a windows Group Policy or a custom AD sign-in script:

[image]

See:

- [Set Visual Studio Formatting Options for an entire team](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684996/736079)